# Gradle init project for Scala application

Tags: scala, gradle

I want to create a skeleton console app for Scala i.e. a single entry class with a main function that prints "Hello world".

I was able to create a Scala library init project by executing:

`gradle init --type scala-library`

however there seems to be no scala-application, running:

`gradle init --type scala-application`

> The requested build setup type 'scala-application' is not supported. Supported types: 'basic', 'groovy-application', 'groovy-library', 'java-application', 'java-library', 'pom', 'scala-library'.

Is there no Scala console app template for Gradle?

Comment: Is there any disclaimer why Gradle do not contains any template for Scala App?

Comment: You can start with a java-application project and then add the 'scala' plug-in as described in the gradle documentation for the scala plugin: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no scala application template, however it is easy to make your generated "scala-library" project into a scala application in two steps:

1. Create your main class and method under a package under src/main/scala
2. Add two lines to your gradle.build, to add the 'application' plugin and specify your main class.

For example, you add src/main/scala/com/example/myapp/Main.scala:

```
package com.example.myapp

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello")
  }
}
```

Then to your gradle.build you add:

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName='com.example.myapp.Main'
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason we have to do it this way? Do we have a more native way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

On top of what you have for `Java` you pretty much only need to add `apply plugin: 'scala'` and change `Main` to be:

```
object Main extends App {
    println('Hello, World!')
}
```

I ended up doing just that.

Additionally, if you want joint compilation (and have compiler understand `Java` and `Scala` in the same place) you can add the below snippet (one block per source set: `main`, `test`, `jmh`, etc.):

```
sourceSets.main {
    java.srcDirs = []
    scala.srcDirs = ['src/main/scala', 'src/main/java']
    scala.include '**/*.*'
}

sourceSets.test {
    java.srcDirs = []
    scala.srcDirs = ['src/test/scala', 'src/test/java']
    scala.include '**/*.*'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of [Gradle 6.7](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/build_init_plugin.html) the `scala-application` build type exists now.